# What is the status of Microsoft "ribbon" licensing as of 2017?

Tags: intellectual-property, licensing

In 2007, the ["fluent UI" or ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing)) had IP rights asserted and [required a license](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jensenh/2006/11/21/licensing-the-2007-microsoft-office-user-interface/) from Microsoft. That license is now [no longer available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/aa973809.aspx), the page only stating 'retired'.

What is the status of using a ribbon UI on Windows or any other platform? Is Microsoft still asserting IP rights, and is a license required?

Note that there are many questions online about this, but no answer, much less a sourced one stating Microsoft's official position. This leaves many developers in a state of uncertainty.

---

As of 2017:

- No documentation on MSDN *anywhere* mentions a license.  Consider, for example, the [MFC ribbon overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcribbonbar-class).
- The VC++ 2017 MFC `CMFCRibbonBar` class, the only ribbon installed with VS2017, links to the retired license in its header. This header has not changed for many years. Its documentation does not mention a license.
- The Visual Studio 2017 license does not mention the ribbon.
- The Windows 10 SDK license does not mention the ribbon (checked against 10.0.15603.137, downloaded 2017-04-11.)
- Some believe this means [no-one who did not sign a license before it was retired are able to legally use a ribbon](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/ribbon-controls-in-rad-studio-10-1-berlin).
- A 2009 comment in a forum (not a good basis) states there are ["no unusual licensing requirements"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/b43aa9cc-0aac-44b5-afb9-af66a9997225/what-is-the-windows-ribbon-license?forum=windowsribbondevelopment).
- There has been no statement by Microsoft of a change in its attitude the the ribbon, arguably meaning that now a license is no longer available, no developers can use a ribbon.
- Microsoft uses a ribbon in its macOS Office applications, but has not indicated if other developers may use a ribbon on non-Windows platforms
- There is significant doubt [if the ribbon is valid IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing)#Patent_controversy).

This leaves all developers who did not sign a license prior to it being retired in limbo and uncertainty, not knowing:

- If they can use the inbuilt WinAPI ribbon control on Windows 10 without a license
- If they can use a third party ribbon control on Windows without a license
- If they can use a third party ribbon control on macOS or Linux
- If they can use a ribbon for an application that competes with a Microsoft application (either Office, or other.)

> Please cite sources, and prefer the kind of sources you could quote if
>   it became legally important, above sources that are a comment on a forum. I'm seeking a
>   definitive answer, and won't mark a "it's probably ok, you'll get away with it"
>   answer as correct.

Comment: Anyone know what happened to [Microsoft's lawsuit against Corel](http://www.zdnet.com/article/design-patent-wars-redux-microsoft-vs-corel-for-the-office-ribbon/) (filed in late 2015)? Tried googling, didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The available evidence (sparse!) suggests that it cannot be done (or can be in a restricted way, see technobabble below). A non-authoritative report (from a developer who had to drop it) is [here](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/ribbon-controls-in-rad-studio-10-1-berlin). A [snapshot of a MS support page](http://archive.is/YrReE) from 2013 on Office UI licensing for developers (also preserved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130514015336/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx)) says:

> The Office UI licensing program, originally launched in November 2006,
>   has been retired. When the program was introduced in 2006, developer
>   frameworks for the Office Ribbon did not exist. Microsoft tools and
>   technologies now provide developers a variety of options, code, and
>   developer frameworks for implementing the Office Ribbon UI in Windows
>   applications.
>
> If you are a developer that already signed up for the Office UI
>   licensing program and accepted the licensing terms, then you will
>   continue to have rights under that license to implement the Office UI
>   per the terms of that license. There are no changes at all for
>   existing Office UI program licensees.
>
> If you are not already licensed to use the Office UI under the retired
>   program, you can use any of the Microsoft tools and frameworks to
>   implement the Ribbon UI in your current or future Windows
>   applications. The license terms associated with the Microsoft
>   developer framework will apply. For example, current developer
>   frameworks that are licensed for creating a Ribbon UI include:
>
> Microsoft Ribbon for Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   Windows Ribbon Framework
>   Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and the .NET Framework 4
>   Ribbon Extensibility Overview
>   Microsoft Foundation Class Ribbon Component (The MFC ribbon may now be used under the same license as the Microsoft Windows SDK).
>
> If you are not already licensed under the Office UI licensing program,
>   and you do not want to use any of the Microsoft tools and
>   technologies, Microsoft no longer has a separate Office Ribbon UI
>   licensing program. If you have any questions about the retired
>   licensing program, please email the officeui@microsoft.com email
>   alias.

So apparently you can do it using MS tools, but not totally on your own.

Comment: Unfortunately, that email address (officeui@microsoft.com) bounces.

Comment: When they say retired, they apparently mean it.